# Android - connecting two searching users algorithm

Tags: android, video, connection, call

I am developing a Random Video Chat App, which will allow users to search and find new people to do video chat, i am done with other functionalities like profile, video calling etc, but now i am stuck in a problem and that is:

**When a bunch of users starts searching from different places, i need to connect pairs of two users with each others, like userA, userB, userC, userD, userE starts searching, i want to connect userA->userB, userC->userD and let the userE wait for another user or connect if other user is avaiable!**

Please help me out with the algotrithm, Thanks!

Comment: I am following [Azar App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azarlive.android)

Comment: the algorithm you need is really up to the functionality of the app ... will it be random connections, geography based, matching based on profile similarities (or differences), experience with the app or something else. queuing (eg for your userE) could be polling based (to make sure they've not abandoned). see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the sorts of problems that will get good answers

Comment: I think I've explained my problem clearly, still apologies for your inconvenience, Have a good day!